# Export objects from 3Ds max 2010 with V-Ray masked to Virtools

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm doing a project on virtual reality. I'm doing a virtual walk-through of an museum.

I have done the 3D from 3Ds Max 2010 and I have used `V-Ray` to map the background and stuff.
I'm using `Virtools` to do the walkthrough. I can export files from 3Ds Max 2010 to `Virtools`. But it doesn't export `V-Ray` maps to the object.

I want to know how to export `V-Ray` maped objects from 3Ds Max 2010 to `Virtools`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bake the textures to the objects if you want to use unsupported textures \ shaders.

Use the texture baking tools found by pressing '0'.